# DB2 Query Token SMALLINT was not valid

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

Forum.

I am working with IBM System i Version 7.1.

I am having issues in the source code with the following merge statement so I copied it over to the database client to utilize the "Run SQL Scripts" functionality.

Rather than replacing the coded in @Variables in the statement I wanted to declare local variables so that I could test the statement as is.

The added the following 'declare and set' lines and I get the following error:

```
declare @groupId smallint
set @groupId = 99

declare @groupName varchar(40)
set @groupName = 'Sam'
```

> declare @groupId smallint
>
> SQL State: 42601
>   Vendor Code: -104
>   Message: [SQL0104] Token SMALLINT was not valid. Valid tokens: DYNAMIC SENSITIVE ASENSITIVE INSENSITIVE. Cause . . . . . :   A syntax
>   error was detected at token SMALLINT.  Token SMALLINT is not a valid
>   token.  A partial list of valid tokens is DYNAMIC SENSITIVE ASENSITIVE
>   INSENSITIVE.  This list assumes that the statement is correct up to
>   the token.  The error may be earlier in the statement, but the syntax
>   of the statement appears to be valid up to this point. Recovery  . . .
>   :   Do one or more of the following and try the request again: --
>   Verify the SQL statement in the area of the token SMALLINT. Correct
>   the statement.  The error could be a missing comma or quotation mark,
>   it could be a misspelled word, or it could be related to the order of
>   clauses. -- If the error token is , correct the SQL
>   statement because it does not end with a valid clause.
>
> Processing ended because the highlighted statement did not complete >successfully

I have tried adding semicolons to the end of each line and begin and end statements and still no success.

Below is the whole statement I am trying to execute:

```
declare @groupId smallint
set @groupId = 99

declare @groupName varchar(40)
set @groupName = 'Sam'


merge into database.table as t 
                 using ( values( cast(@groupId as smallint) 
                 ,cast(@groupName as varchar(40)) 
                 )) 
                 as caz( group_id
    , group_name
    ) 
                 on t.group_id = caz.group_id 
                 when matched then update
                 set t.group_name = caz.group_name 
                 when not matched then 
                 insert (   group_id
    , group_name
    ) 
                 values (caz.group_id
    , caz.group_name
    );
```

Any help is appreciated.

Please let me know if I may provide anymore information.

Comment: It might be a good idea to read about the correct syntax of [compound statements in the manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzcompoundstmt.htm?lang=en).

Comment: Not only syntax. The [docs also say this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzdeclvar.htm?lang=en) about DECLARE VARIABLE: "**Invocation** This statement can only be embedded in an application program."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4451159/2272357

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VARIABLE variableName VARCHAR(50);
SET variableName = 'blah';
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = variableName;
DROP VARIABLE variableName;
```

I have yet to verify it works successfully. I believe it may be a local issue though.

Comment: Silly to code a separate `SET` statement in the given example; just add the `DEFAULT` clause to assign the value during the `CREATE`. So was that verification done? If that was successful, then seems appropriate to accept the answer.?